# Why is there a user called CouchDB Administrator on my system?

Tags: login, users, couchdb

It's clogging up my GDM login screen. Also, what would happen if I deleted this user?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu is this? Also, is this a fresh install, or did you do some other stuff on it beforehand?

Comment: This is the latest ubuntu, and recently updated. It's not a completely fresh install--I've messed around with it a bunch. I didn't do anything to it before I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is an Apache project.

CouchDB is a database that completely embraces the web. Store your data with JSON documents. Access your documents with your web browser, via HTTP. Query, combine, and transform your documents with JavaScript.

CouchDB works well with modern web and mobile apps. You can even serve web apps directly out of CouchDB. And you can distribute your data, or your apps, efficiently using CouchDB’s incremental replication. CouchDB supports master-master setups with automatic conflict detection.

to remove :

```
sudo apt-get purge couchdb
```

If you want to find out what maybe uses couchdb on your system, you can use `apt-cache rdepends couchdb`:

```
> apt-cache rdepends couchdb   
couchdb
Reverse Depends:
  python-couchdb
  couchdb-bin
> apt-cache rdepends couchdb-bin
couchdb-bin
Reverse Depends:
  …
  desktopcouch

> apt-cache rdepends desktopcouch
desktopcouch
Reverse Depends:
  …
  desktopcouch-ubuntuone
  xdiagnose
  oneconf
  indicator-weather
  …
  evolution-couchdb
  desktopcouch-ubuntuone
```